# display employes who report to the user id given if user id given is team lead , else display the employes who report to the given user id's

Tags: sql, sql-server

see req: display employes who report to the user id given if user id given is team lead , else display the employes who report to the given user id's team lead the input will be user id

declare @teamLead as int
select @teamLead=Report_To from TM_USER where TM_UserID=106
(select distinct emp.TM_UserID,emp.FullName,TL.FullName as TeamLead from TM_User EMP
join TM_User TL on emp.Report_To=tl.TM_UserID where ( emp.Report_To=@teamLead or emp.TM_UserID=@teamLead ))

Comment: asnswer to my question any one

Comment: What *is* your question? You've got a title and a piece of code. What is your problem at this point, what isn't working, what have you tried in order to solve the problem?

Comment: u can see my question and reqment above Andriy M

Comment: Hey, I've only just noticed that you've changed your post *completely* several times since first posting it. That is not how things work at this site. When you have a problem to ask about, you post a question. When you have a *different* problem, you post a *new* question. It's true that sometimes questions stay unanswered for a long time (some never get answered), but if you are going to use the same post to ask about very different things, things will quickly become *very* messy and that will just drive people away from your question(s). So please don't do that.

Comment: And you haven't answered my questions about what *particularly* poses a problem for you at this moment and what you've *already* tried. So far your question sounds like "I want *(your goal)*, please do that for me", while people are more likely to help if they see your personal effort in trying to solve the problem. So again, please state what *exactly* is the problem for you now (why you cannot solve the problem yourself), what you have tried and how that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Task.end_date is part of inner query. Change it to a.end_date.